# Is subclassing uinavigationcontroller wise or risky?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

Is there any official prohibition on subclassing uinavigationcontroller? It seems to me a risky thing to do, especially if Apple changes it.

Comment: Nothing risky if you'd use only Public API of UINavigationController

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem with sub-classing UINavigationController; I've done it on several occasions to provide functionality not supported by the delegate such as dependency injection in managed view controllers. Take a look at the delegate methods to see if they can accomplish what you need and if not, subclass on.

Comment: You mean you have the nav controller provide the dependency object rather than the earlier view controller that pushed a new view controller? I'm all for lateral dependency injection but what does injecting from the nav controller get you?

Comment: I was doing DI with a "DependencyProvider" protocol that supplied all possible dependencies (each described by its own protocol). Individual view controllers would accept the provider object and cherry-pick the dependencies it needed. Saves on signature refactoring when a new dependency is needed, but still allows me to substitute mock dependency objects for unit tests. The nav controller takes a dependency source and offers it to every view controller it parents.